# Azure DevOps extension using React: Can't stop navigating away from the page(beforeunload event)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

The azure-devops-extension-sdk has events that can be listened to for work items like onLoaded, onRefreshed, onUnloaded etc. But there's no event to listen to while the web page itself is being refreshed(navigating away). I need to stop the navigation action in case there are unsaved changes in my custom UI element. Azure DevOps does this inherently only in those cases where a standard backend field is used. My custom UI element (installed using an extension I developed) doesn't use any backend fields.

window.addEventListener function doesn't seem to work and neither did the window.beforeunload function.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are using a hub extension. We could not use the window.beforeunload event of the browser which is not working in the case of an extension because it is running in an iframe.

After go through [azure-devops-extension-api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-api/ihostnavigationservice), didn't find any related interface. Afraid this is not available for a customized extension right now.

Comment: I'm creating a control type of extension which will be added to an existing work item. I thought the onUnloaded event would take care of the navigation scenario too. But seems like that's not the case. Any workaround that you may be able to suggest?

Comment: Afraid not. You could submit a user voice. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/visual-studio-team-services.html?type=idea Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: There's already a feature request submitted by another user. I'll wait for a reply on that. Meanwhile I have found a workaround by using a backend field and the setError function in conjunction. Not a good user experience, but will get the work done for now.

Comment: @SaleelAli Thanks for your kindly response. You could also share your solution here and mark it as a reply. Which will also help others in the community.